# Choose elements from numpy matrix depending on set of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix in numpy in python and I need to choose the elements in the thirds columns when the element in the first column is 1 or 2 and in the second column is 2 or 4.

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.matrix('1 2 5; 3 4 3; 2 3 2; 2 4 5; 1 3 2; 3 2 2')
```

I tried this code but it is not working.

```
l1 = np.array([1, 2])
l2 = np.array([2, 4])
result = a[(a[:,0] in l1) & (a[:,1] in l2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
l1 = np.array([1, 2])
l2 = np.array([2, 4])
result = a[np.in1d(a[:,0], l1) & np.in1d(a[:,1], l2)]

result
#matrix([[1, 2, 5],
#        [2, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Thx, That exactly what I need :)